# Scanner and ArrayList with letters

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to declare an arrayList named "courses" but I have a problem in my code. I also want to do a print of the note and of the course.

```
ArrayList<Integer> listNotes = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> listCourses = new ArrayList();

int notes;
String[] courses = {"Science", "History", "English"};

 for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
   //System.out.print((i+1) + " note(s) : ");
   System.out.print((courses[i]) + " Note : ");
   notes = INPUT.nextInt();
   listNotes.add(notes);
 }

 System.out.print("Display : " );
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: @DaveNewton I also want to do a print of the note and of the course.

Comment: You've described what you *want*, but we need to know what the problem is that you're having. Apparently your code doesn't do what you want? What  is it supposed to do and what does it do now instead?

Comment: @julie Okay, what' the problem?

Comment: @JJJ: I want to display the resultas of my 2 arrayList :-(

Comment: You are printing the course names and the grades in the first line of the for loop, correct? Does it work the way you want it to work? edit: I see you are never printing your input of what grade you are typing in. Is the problem that the grade is not displayed?

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to display the resultas of my 2 arrayList :-(

Comment: @ Ivo Vidovic: no unfortunately :-( https://repl.it/repls/ClearcutLividPatterns

Comment: The problem is in your for-loop. You are iterating your for-loop 5 times while your course array that's printing is only 3 in length

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/UnsungBraveParticles

Comment: @ youassassin: my problem is resolve. thank for your help my friend.

Answer (score 1):

youassassin is correct, your problem is that your for loop iterates too many times, otherwise your code is doing what it is supposed to do.

Whenever you are iterating over an array, the safest way to do so is to use its length in the termination condition.

```
for(int i=0; i < courses.length; i++) {
  //System.out.print((i+1) + " note(s) : ");
  System.out.print((courses[i]) + " Note : ");
  notes = INPUT.nextInt();
  listNotes.add(notes);
}
```

This approach gives you advantages in case you are handling arrays of different sizes or handle arrays that are changing. For example if you want to extend your courses array, you will not have to adjust the amount of iterations your loop has to do, because your loop itself is going to look up the size of your array and make one iteration per arrayelement.

Comment: thank you. Now I want to print but it not works.... :-(  System.out.print(courses[i] + notes[i] + "notes");

Comment: Do you mean you want to print all elements of the ArrayList ListNotes? the variable notes is just an int, not an int[], therefore notes[i] should give you a syntax error

Comment: @ Ivo Vidovic: my problem is resolve. thank for your help my friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> listNotes = new ArrayList(); ArrayList<String> listCourses = new ArrayList(); 
int notes; 
String[] courses = {"Science", "History", "English"}; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i<courses.length;i++){
 //System.out.print((i+1) + " note(s) : "); System.out.print((courses[i]) + " Note :"); 
notes = input.nextInt(); listNotes.add(notes); } System.out.print("Display : " );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> listNote = new ArrayList();

        int note = 0;
        String[] cours = {"Math", "Geo", "Os"};
        double somme = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<cours.length;i++){
            System.out.print(cours[i] + " : " );
            note = INPUT.nextInt();
            listNote.add(note);
            somme = somme + note;
        }

        //System.out.print("La note est de " + somme);
        double moyenne = somme / 3;
        System.out.println("Résumé");

        for(int i = 0; i<cours.length;i++){
            System.out.println(cours[i] + " " +  listNote.get(i));
        }

        System.out.print("moyenne = " + moyenne);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer you an alternate solution using a HashMap:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        Map<String, String> courses = new HashMap<>();
        //courses.put("add your course here","add your note here");
        courses.put("science", "my notes my notes on Science");
        courses.put("history", "my notes on History");
        courses.put("english", "my notes on English");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Which note would you like to check out?");
            input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            if (courses.keySet().contains(input))
                System.out.println("Found notes on " + input + ": " + courses.get(input));
            else
                System.out.println("Couldn't find notes on " + input);
            System.out.println("Another search? (Y/N)");
            input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if (input.equals("n"))
                break;
        }
    }
}
```